# How to solve $x^3−x+1=0$

Tags: polynomials, cubics, roots-of-cubics

I am interested in finding a solution for the equation:

$$ x^3 - x + 1 = 0 $$

I've noticed that there are numerous polynomial equations where one of the coefficients is zero. Could you provide guidance on solving such equations? Additionally, if you could recommend any resources for further exploration, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There is an exact way to solve this, but usually numerical methods are applied.

Comment: [depressed cubics](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/)

Comment: By "exact", @Peter means in terms of radicals. For what it's worth, the same "it exists but people usually work numerically" fact also applies to quartics, [but not to quintics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: If you investigate depressed cubics and Cardano's formula, you'll find a way to write the solution using square roots and cube roots. For this particular equation, the real root can be written $-\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{3 (9 - \sqrt{69})}} - \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{\frac12 (9 - \sqrt{69})}}{3^{2/3}}$, which comes out to about $-1.3247$. What the comment above says is that if you're looking for a result like $-1.3247$, most people would just use an algorithm that does some sophisticated form of trial and error to get close to the exact result.

Answer (score 3):

Write $x$ as $u + v$. Then you could write the equation as $(u+v)^3 - (u+v) + 1 = 0$. Expanding it out, you get:

$$u^3 + 3 u^2 v + 3 u v^2 + v^3 - (u + v) + 1 = (u^3 + v^3 + 1) + 3uv(u+v)-(u+v)=0 = (u^3+v^3+1) + (3uv-1)(u+v)=0.$$

Forcing $u^3+v^3+1$ and $3uv-1$ to be $0$, you get that the following must be true:

$$\begin{cases}u^3+v^3=-1 \\ u^3 v^3 = \frac{1}{27} \end{cases}$$

At this point you know the sum and the product of $u^3$ and $v^3$, so you can solve
for them through a quadratic equation (or you could just solve the system of equation I wrote earlier):

$$x^2 - (u^3 + v^3)x + u^3 v^3 = 0 \iff x^2 + x + \frac{1}{27},$$

which is solved for $x = -\frac{1}2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}}6$. Then you get
that $u^3$ is equal to one of those roots, while $v^3$ is the other.
Then, since $x = u + v$, you get the solution you wanted:

$$x = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}2 + \frac{\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}}6} + \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}2 - \frac{\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}}6} \approx -1.3247.$$

Now you can get the other two roots by using Ruffini's rule and solving another quadratic equation. You can generalise this process to solve all the cubics of the form $x^3 + bx + c = 0$, as [AlvinL](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/229673/alvinl) pointed out in a comment -- this is known as Cardano's rule.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could prefer
$$x=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$ obtained following the steps described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions)